# Check from JQuery if value exists in ViewBag

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, viewbag

I trying to check if value in **ViewBag** exists or not from `JQuery` :

```
if("<%: ViewBag.isSearchEnabled %>" != null && "<%: ViewBag.isSearchEnabled %>" != "True")
        {
        $("#CompanySearchPanel").hide();
        }
```

This should be working according to [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11317784/check-viewbag-value-is-present-in-javascript) but it is giving following error :

```
The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'System.IO.TextWriter.Write(string, params object[])' and 'System.IO.TextWriter.Write(char[])'
```

Just for the info, this value does not exists in **ViewBag**.

Can someone help me here ?

Comment: Looking at the link, it uses razor syntax. What does `<%:` mean? Are you on asp.net mvc?

Comment: Yes. But this HTML format.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC "The call is ambiguous" Error (System.IO.TextWriter.Write)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462211/asp-net-mvc-the-call-is-ambiguous-error-system-io-textwriter-write)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462211/asp-net-mvc-the-call-is-ambiguous-error-system-io-textwriter-write) link wherein it is mentioned type casting is the solution. Was not aware that type casting is required. I just did this and it is working.

Please suggest if this is the correct reason or not.